# How do you sculpt without messing up geometry?

Tags: uv, sculpting, faces, uv-image-editor

I feel like I must be doing something fundamentally wrong in blender. Every time I sculpt I seem to create geometry where faces overlap/edges inside of faces. unintentionally. I can even be very careful smoothing a few faces, and somehow I created overlapping geometry. Not to mention what creating creases does to the geometry.

I then find myself having to go to layout/UV Editing, where I need to fix this in order for paint/texture to work out correctly.

Later when I am painting I find more overlapping vertices, so I remap all the UV faces, which of course messes up all the painting I have done so far.

It seems like as soon as I get to the painting part, I find geometry I need to fix - that I would not have been able to detect as easily without trying painting first, so I remap because of this one section of geometry, which means I have to repaint everything. And by remapping It somehow exposes more geometry issues that I didn't see before. And I have live unwrap on, yet I still need to remap when I remove a face only sometimes - not sure what determines when, but if I don't, it starts drawing on multiple faces when I draw on i. It seems like a lot of redoing just to get anywhere.

Any help appreciated!

Thanks,

Comment: Most 3D sculptures are a base for a model, never the final model because of the amount of geometry that sculpting creates. When you make a sculpture, the next step is to perform a retopology in order to get a better geometry for you model. Once you have that new model, you can UV unwrap and finally paint your model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those struggling with the same thing, I would highly recommend selecting all faces, and in the UV editor going to

Select -> Select Overlap.

This made is so I wasn't unware of overlapping faces that I would need to unwrap only after finding them through not being able to paint them. Very surprised someone more experienced had not pointed this out, and would have helped...